# Excel: Remove word from a string and show exact word in adjacent cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have spent a few days trying to figure the below out - can you help?

```
| I have   this in Column(A):       | And I need the   Brand name in column(A): | ...and product   description in Column (B):  |
|-----------------------------------|-------------------------------------------|-----------------------------------------------|
| Stanley Fatmax   Knife Saw Blades | Stanley Fatmax                            | Knife Saw Blades                              |
| Yale Lock   Brass                 | Yale                                      | Lock Brass                                    |
```

The problem is that some brand names have 2 words, and not every entry in the column has a brand name.

NB.  I have a list identifying the exact brands names 200, so identifying them shouldn't be a problem?

Comment: where is your list with brand names ?

Comment: On a Notepad, but can easily move to another column or sheet of required.

Comment: e.g. 
AA  
Abru  
Absco

Comment: Ok for now paste it into column C and ill edit my answer below

Comment: Excel column names include `A`, `B`, `C`, etc... there is no Column `2(B)`. Please [edit] your question to use correct nomenclature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, These formulas require an exact match to a Brand Name in the list of allowable Brand Names, and also produce a blank result when no Brand Name can be found.

[image]

This array formula in B2:

`=IFERROR(INDEX(D$2:D$6,MATCH(1,FIND(D$2:D$6,A2),0)),"")`

must be entered with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> and then filled down.

The FIND() portion of this formula tries to find the whole list of Brand Names in the Description in A2.  It returns an array with a #VALUE error everywhere except where there's a match (exact), and it gives a 1 in that position.  MATCH() finds the position of the 1, and then INDEX() reads the correct Brand Name out of the list.  The IFERROR() produces a blank if a valid Brand Name was not found.

This formula in C2, filled down:

`=IF(B2="","",MID(A2,LEN(B2)+2,LEN(A2)-LEN(B2)-1))`

just removes the Brand Name from the description and spits out what's left. And it also produces a blank if the Brand Name wasn't found.  But note that if you add "Stanley Leverlock" in Column D above, then the correct Brand Name and Product will be filled in.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you - this answers my question exactly.  Appreciate all the help from all.

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this would work,

in B1:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1, 'YOUR BRAND NAMES RANGE HERE', 1, TRUE)
```

Then drag down

**edit as per comments:**

try using the below in B1:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,C:C,1,TRUE)
```

Comment: That works great for the most-part thanks!  However, it comes up with predicted words for items that don't have brand names.   e.g. (A1)Compact Cash Register (B1 Results)Colron -when it should be blank

Comment: Can you ask the formula to look for exact results only and if not, show nothing?

Comment: yeah should be able to do it, ill have a go as soon as im finished up doing a bit of work

Comment: For exact match in VLOOKUP(), just change TRUE to FALSE in the last part of the formula.

Comment: Hmm, just comes up with N/A# for all results.  The result needs to be an exact match of the word within the string.  But I think changing to FALSE queries the whole string?

Comment: Also results with TRUE seem to go for the longer of the brand names: "Dulux Wild Primrose" results chooses the longer brand name over the shorter.  E.g.  Result is "Dulux Trade" rather than the exact match "Dulux" from the brand list.

Comment: You're correct that VLOOKUP() with False queries the whole string and with True, it will find the first approximate match in the list.  So...., VLOOKUP doesn't work well here if you want exact matches.  See my suggestion in the answer elsewhere on this page using INDEX/MATCH with a FIND() inside to force the exact match.